# sqoop import performance tuning by hardcoding boundary values

Tags: import, sqoop, boundary

I am trying to increase the sqoop import time, while running sqoop import with split by key and mappers.
It  generates a boundary value finding query (

```sql
19/01/09 00:32:37 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: 
  SELECT MIN(TO_TIMESTAMP(USR_ACTN_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')), 
         MAX(TO_TIMESTAMP(USR_ACTN_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')) 
  FROM DB_schema.TABLENAME 
  WHERE ( USR_ACTN_DT > to_date('2018-12-03 19:45:12','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') )
```

).

For me the boundary query takes around 12+ hours to get a response, I know the boundary value which needs to be passed.
**Is there a way to pass the boundary values directly in sqoop import instead of boundary query..?**

Answer (score 0):

As you know the boundary values which need to passed, you can give that values under --boundary-query argument as --boundary-query 'select 1,100'

Let me know, if it's not work.